# Create a php script(model) in codeigniter which is triggered via command line to create a csv file of a database

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, command-line

I need to write a php script which can be called from the command line (likely to be a model from the mvc platform) which will in turn create and download a csv file which is a representation of a relational database, based on a mysql query in the php script.

I am new to using a mvc platform for programming with php. What is the recommended approach to programming whilst under the constraints of the mvc platform, for example where do my DB credentials belong and what do i call from the command line?..the model or controller. Furthermore i am running the script via command line therefore see no need for a view.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can write the application in normal way and call that web URL from the command line.
like

```
curl http://www.exsample./index.php/backup
```

in this method you can parse parameters as get variables like

```
curl http://www.example.com/index.php/backup?para1=mypara
```

or if you have project in your local pc with php you can call it like this

```
php /var/home/site/myprojet/index.php/backup
```

With parameters

```
php /var/home/site/myprojet/index.php/backup paraone
```

in php use $argv to recieve argument values

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Thank you. So would this just be a single php script which houses the DB credentials, sql query and header/download operations to create the csv file?

Comment: Yes it can be a one php file with all the coding or several files with distributed structure.
This can work with codeigniter too (Not tested)

Comment: I have tried what you said previously and it just opens the file in the browser. For example i have a php file with the following:

<?php
function doThis(){
echo "Hello World";
}
?>

And it just prints the entire file on the browser as oppose to returning just Hello World.

Comment: What is the code you tried and what is you OS

i just typed `curl www.google.com` in my teminal and it printed some html to the terminal. But this can happen if you use `start www.google.com` command in windows.